# Their was an error in evaluation the Pre-request Script: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm trying to access the response of my POST request in Postman via Pre-request Script.

**Script given below :**

```
var mobiles = postman.environment.get("mobiles");

if (!mobiles)
  {
    mobiles =["8824444866","8058506668"];  
  }

var currentMobile = mobiles.shift();
postman.environement.set("mobile","currentMobile");
postman.environement.set("mobiles",mobiles);
```

When I click on Send button, in the postman it shows an error, which is given below:

> Their was an error in evaluation the Pre-request Script: Cannot read
>   property 'get' of undefined.

Please suggest some solution

Comment: obviously `environment` is undefined here, what does a `console.log(postman)` shows to you?

Answer (score 2):

What you were trying/looking for is `postman.setEnvironmentVariable(key, value)` and you can use the new one which is `pm.environment.set(key, value)` and of course it's shorthand for the same feature.

It's `pm` which has the access to the environment API and not `postman`.
Also, you have got a typo in your script.
It's `environment`, while you've `environement` in your script where you're setting the variable.

Here's the fixed script:

***NOTE: This will only work on the native app***

```
var mobiles = pm.environment.get("mobiles");

if (!mobiles)
  {
    mobiles =["8824444866","8058506668"];  
  }

var currentMobile = mobiles.shift();
pm.environment.set("mobile", currentMobile);
pm.environment.set("mobiles", mobiles);
```

In case you want to use `postman.*` API then the script for that would be:

***For Chrome App & Native App (Legacy Support)***

```
var mobiles = postman.getEnvironmentVariable("mobiles");

if (!mobiles)
  {
    mobiles =["8824444866","8058506668"];  
  }

var currentMobile = mobiles.shift();
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("mobile", currentMobile);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("mobiles", mobiles);
```

Comment: still facing the issue,

Comment: its shows Their was an error in evaluation the Pre-request Script: pm is not defined.

Comment: @AmitSheoran I think you're using the chrome app. Use the second script that I posted for chrome app. However, I strongly advise you to use the Native App. The chrome app has been deprecated.

Comment: Please help this also

Comment: @AmitSheoran Additionally, you can reach out to Postman Community as our whole team and the community is constantly helping out each other. Here: https://community.getpostman.com/latest